# How to reset the selection date range when click on reset icon swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I implemented a calendar view to select date range. That working fine but I want to reset the selection date when click on reset button. 
I'm using DTCalendarPods for selection of date range.

Please Help me If any body knows about this.

Cocoa pods links: [Git Link](https://github.com/Dynamit/DTCalendarView-iOS)

Here is the screen shot.

[image: Screen Shot]

How to clear the selected range when user click on reset icon (in screen shot the button is at beside of close button).

Comment: Please add your source code, you have tried for this.

Comment: I've found there is `setupCollectionViewReload()` function inside that library, unfortunately, it's private class. Could you try like 'myCalandar.reload()'?

Comment: Just downloaded source code from the link https://github.com/Dynamit/DTCalendarView-iOS & added one close & reset button. If u want to see the source code please click on above link. Please help me if you know some thing

Comment: @PyaePhyoeShein Thanks for the reply. I'm new to swift can you please explain in detail about myCalandar.reload()'

Comment: @Karthik I've post answer. Please check it out and mark as answer and pls upvote it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very sample solution I've found:

```
@IBAction func resetCalendar(_ sender: Any) {
    calendarView.selectionStartDate = nil
    calendarView.selectionEndDate = nil
}
```

Next time, you better read its documentation and found its function first.

Comment: @Karthik - Accept and upvote answer, if this solution works.